# How can I read the current React.useRef in the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React.useRef in the parent component `const portfolioRef = React.useRef(null)` And want to use the current version of that in the child component `const parent = portfolioRef.current`. But when I use it in this way, it says `cannot read property of current`. Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
export function Portfolio() {
  const portfolioRef = React.useRef(null)
  return (
    <div  className={cx(styles.component, styles.scrollWrapper)}>
      <div className={styles.topIcon} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: arrow }} />
      <div ref={portfolioRef} className={styles.scroll}>
       <PortfolioItem
          title='Article about Kaliber Academie'
          text='I wrote an article about my experience at Kaliber'
          link='https://medium.com/kaliberinteractive/hoe-technologie-het-hart-van-een-luie-scholier-veranderde-3cd3795c6e33'
          linkTekst='See Article' />

       </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function PortfolioItem({ text, title, link, linkTekst, portfolioRef }) {
  const portfolioItemRef = React.useRef(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
   const element = portfolioItemRef.current
   const parent = portfolioRef.current
   calculateDistance(parent, element)
   }, [portfolioRef])

  return (
    <div ref={portfolioItemRef} className={styles.componentItem}>
     <div className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
      <div className={styles.content}>
       <div className={styles.text}>{text}</div>
        <div className={styles.links}>
          <a className={styles.linkTekst} href={link}>{linkTekst} </a>
          <div className={styles.linkIcon} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
           __html:arrow }} />
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function calculateDistance(parent, element) {
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect()
  const parentCenter = parentRect.top + parentRect.height / 2
  const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  const elementCenter = elementRect.top + elementRect.height / 2
  const distance = Math.abs(elementCenter - parentCenter)
  console.log(distance)
}
```

Comment: Can't see PortfolioItem being rendered inside the parent Portfolio

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Added to the code

Comment: The parent ref even if you pass as props to child will not be accessible in child in first render since at that time the ref isn't initialised in the parent. Could you show what you are trying to achieve in calculate distance so that an alternative can be suggested

Answer (score 2):

```
function PortfolioItem({ text, title, link, linkTekst, portfolioRef }) {
    const portfolioItemRef = React.useRef(null) //line 1

    const element = portfolioItemRef.current //line 2

    const parent = portfolioRef.current //line 3

    calculateDistance(parent, element)
    return (
        <div ref={portfolioItemRef} className={styles.componentItem}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

when the code execute in order

- Line #1: create a reference to hold an element or value by using `useRef` nad initiate it to null,
- Line #2: trying to access current value of the ref which is still `null` //Error, because ref is not holding any value at this moment

to access the value you have to put the logic inside useRef

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const element = portfolioItemRef.current
    const parent = portfolioRef.current
    calculateDistance(parent, element)
}, [])
```

not tested.

Comment: Do you mean useRef or useEffect?

Comment: Do you also know a solution for use the function `calculateDistance` on the `onScroll` event on the div with `className scroll`?

Comment: attacha  a scroll event listner and call the function

Comment: Yeeah, i know but the useEffect with the variables are in the child. So when i call the function `calculateDistance` in the parent, it cannot reach the variables in the child. So is it better to move the useEffect to the parent? I updated the file so you can see how it is now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't pass the ref to the child at all. Try to pass it in props

```
<PortfolioItem
  portfolioRef={portfolioRef} {/* here you are passing the ref in props */}
  title="Article about Kaliber Academie"
  text="I wrote an article about my experience at Kaliber"
  link="https://medium.com/kaliberinteractive/hoe-technologie-het-hart-van-een-luie-scholier-veranderde-3cd3795c6e33"
  linkTekst="See Article"
/>;
```